# Parse Server - Reset user password - custom html page

Tags: parse-server

Does someone know if it is possible to personalize the html page use for reseting user password ? May be by configuration or with some trick ?

Thank you for your answers

Vincent

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It can be done via the **customPages** option. From parse docs:

> customPages - A hash with urls to override email verification links,
>   password reset links and specify frame url for masking user-facing
>   pages. Available keys: parseFrameURL, invalidLink, choosePassword,
>   passwordResetSuccess, verifyEmailSuccess.

So in your case you need to override  the **choosePassword** and **passwordResetSuccess** keys and add your own pages instead.